# Is it a good practice to increase post_file_size from apache configuration to allow uploading of 20MB+ images

Tags: php, apache, post, centos6

Is it a good practice to increase post_file_size (and other needed variables) from apache configuration to allow uploading of 20MB+ images from an `<input type="file">` in php?

I use it to pass the image file to the other page , preview it with a built URI and then, on confirmation, upload it to the server.

Is this the right way to do it?

Production server will use: Centos6, apache , php 5.3

PS: The client is a poster company and needs uploading image of up to 10Kx10K pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Use HTML5 File API to upload large files. which has the concept of slicing, so that you can upload large files.

```
var reader= new FileReader();
reader.onload=function(e){

//do whatever you want with result
}
var blob = file.slice(startingByte, endindByte);//slicing file
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

FileSystem Tutorial:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

File API tutorial :

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/